# How can I use one attribute of the last record when creating a new one

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I need to register one record per day, using the last recorded date, and add one day, because it needs to be correlative.

My new action is:

```
def new
  @farm = Farm.find(params[:farm_id])
  @inspection = @farm.inspections.build
  @last_inspection = @farm.inspections.order('date desc').first
  @inspection.date = @last_inspection.date + 1.day
end
```

but the 'new' form doesn't show the correct date value. It shows an empty date.

Am i missing something?

Regards.

Comment: Please post your form

Comment: Thank you, Amit. I forgot to review my form.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to post my form, I found the error:

```
= form_for [@farm, @farm.inspection.build] do |f|
  = render 'fields', f: f
```

so I was building a new inspection record at the form and was losing the initialization values of controller.

Now, my form is more simple:

```
= form_for @inspection do |f|
  = render 'fields', f: f
```